# SQL Statement where if the next value is the same as the current skip that value

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my table

```
| id | date      | data |
|----|-----------|------|
| 1  | 2019/03/12| data1|
| 2  | 2019/03/12| data2|
| 3  | 2019/03/04| data3|
| 4  | 2019/03/04| data4|
| 5  | 2019/03/04| data5|
| 6  | 2019/03/05| data6|
| 7  | 2019/03/05| data7|
```

My expected results looks like

```
| id | date      | data |
|----|-----------|------|
| 1  | 2019/03/12| data1|
| 3  | 2019/03/04| data3|
| 6  | 2019/03/05| data6|
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is don't show the next row if its date value is the same with the current date value

I have tried

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `table` WHERE `date` = table1.date)";
```

but it always returns 0 results...

Comment: Would not `GROUP BY date` give you the result you are looking for? `SELECT * FROM `table` table1 GROUP BY date`

Comment: @Dave That coincidentally would work for the data given, but it might not always work in general.

Comment: Absolutely @TimBiegeleisen ... it's certainly not a general solution at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic here can be stated as that you want to display a record if either:

- It is the very first record in the table, or
- The record immediately preceding it had a different date value

We can try the following query:

```
SELECT id, date, data
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.date <> (SELECT t2.date FROM table1 t2
                  WHERE t2.id < t1.id ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1) OR
      t1.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table1)
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

[image]

### Demo

**Edit:**

The above solution is one option if you are using MySQL 5.7 or earlier.  If you have access to MySQL 8+, in particular to the `LAG` function, then there is a slightly cleaner way of doing this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, date, data,
        LAG(date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id) date_prev
    FROM table1
)

SELECT id, date, data
FROM cte
WHERE date <> date_prev OR date_prev IS NULL
ORDER BY id;
```

This uses the same logic, but it uses `LAG` to avoid messy and verbose subqueries.

Comment: suppose i have another field like 'time', how can i include it in your query? that if the current field 'time' value is not the same with the next time value, show the row.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking me.  Are you saying that now there is another `time` column in addition to the date?  If so, then I recommend just using a single timestamp column containing the date and time.

Comment: yes, i forgot to include that row time in the question. But yes that would be much better i should just include both date and time in the same row, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use outer join

```
select a.* from `table` as a left join `table` as b on a.id > b.id and a.date=b.date where b.id is null
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3cf3f34d94974d0ec7aabe881b902f92)

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of doing it is to include the following where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` table1 
where id in (select min(`id`) from `table` group by `date`)
```

You're only interested in the rows that are the first row per date. This assumes that your id column is an incremental index and that you're always interested in the first record.